# python re.split with maxsplit argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

when using `re.split` I'd expect the `maxsplit` to be the length of the returned list (-1).

The examples in the docs suggest so.

But when there is a capture group (and maybe some other cases) then I don't understand how the `maxsplit` argument works.

```py
>>> re.split("(\W+)", "Words, words, words.", maxsplit=1)
['Words', ', ', 'words, words.']

>>> re.split("(:)", ":a:b::c", maxsplit=2)
['', ':', 'a', ':', 'b::c']
>>> re.split("((:))", ":a:b::c", maxsplit=2)
['', ':', ':', 'a', ':', ':', 'b::c']
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about `maxsplit`, it's about you using parentheses in the regular expression:

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.

**DOCS:** https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split

Answer (score 1):

So what I'm guessing is that `maxsplit` determines the number of splits, and the parentheses return additional groups.

**Example**
`":a:b::c"` with `maxsplit=2` splits your string in three parts:
"", "a", "b::c"

But because the pattern `"(:)"` also contains a captured group, it's returned in between the parts:
"", ":", "a", ":", "b::c"

If the pattern is `"((:))"`, then each colon is returned twice in between the parts